# Modifying/transforming dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with values date, categories that are randomly assigned from just a letter to 3 char strings, and frequencies ['A', 'B', 'C']

I would like to modify the initial data frame so that I get Date, and each category as a column, assign freqA correlated to the category for the category column, and keep null values as None

How can I accomplish this?

```
This is my df (i forgot to include the index):
+--------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| Date   | Category | freqA | freqB | freqC |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2/1/19 | A        | 2     | 89    | 7     |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2/2/19 | B        | 5     | 98    | 8     |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2/3/19 | A        | 10    | 100   | 12    |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2/4/19 | A        | 17    | 121   | 15    |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2/5/29 | C        | 21    | 133   | 25    |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2/6/19 | C        | 25    | 134   | 31    |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+-------+

This is my target df:
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| Date | CategoryA | CategoryB | CategoryC | Category[a] |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| Date | freqA     | freqA     | freqA     | freqA       |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

I am very new to python and pandas

So, I appreciate all the help I can get

Comment: Please show us something you tried? Also, target df looks weird, you just want `freqA` in the columns or the values of `freqA`

Comment: @Grayrigel I want values of freqA
I have tried something similar with a covid-19 time series dataset but it was built differently from this one
So far I haven't written any code for this data frame

Comment: I have added an answer let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked!

Comment: Glad I could help. Good lucky. Happy coding !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```
#working with subset of your data
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2/1/19','3/1/19','4/1/19', '5/1/19','6/1/19'], 'Category':['A','B','A','A','C'],'freqA':[2,5,10
,17,21],'freqB':[89,98,100,121,133]})

#input data
>>> df
     date Category  freqA  freqB
0  2/1/19        A      2     89
1  3/1/19        B      5     98
2  4/1/19        A     10    100
3  5/1/19        A     17    121
4  6/1/19        C     21    133

#using pivot to reshape the dataframe and renaming the columns
>>> df1 = df.pivot(index ='date', columns='Category',values='freqA')
>>> df1.columns = [f'Category{x}' for x in  df1.columns.tolist()]
>>> print(df1)
```

Output:

```
        CategoryA  CategoryB  CategoryC
date                                   
2/1/19        2.0        NaN        NaN
3/1/19        NaN        5.0        NaN
4/1/19       10.0        NaN        NaN
5/1/19       17.0        NaN        NaN
6/1/19        NaN        NaN       21.0
```

You can also take care of `NaN` values with `fillna`. Here is an example:

```
>>> df1.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
>>> df1.fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)

        CategoryA  CategoryB  CategoryC
date                                   
2/1/19        2.0        5.0       21.0
3/1/19        2.0        5.0       21.0
4/1/19       10.0        5.0       21.0
5/1/19       17.0        5.0       21.0
6/1/19       17.0        5.0       21.0
```